# how to use "or" in hibernate for keyword search through a table fields

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I want to search my table (book) on any of its fields (author_name, book_title, description, publisher name) by keyword, using Hibernate.

I tried using the code below but my code is good enough for only two fields:

**New Update Code** but here "createDisjunction()" is not supporting.Showing error ->The method create disjunction is undefined for the type restrictions

```
           import org.hibernate.Criteria;
           import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
           import org.hibernate.Query;
           import org.hibernate.Session;
           import org.hibernate.SessionFactory; 
           import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
            ............
           ............
           qry.add(Restrictions.createDisjunction()
           //But this 'createDisjunction()'  is showing error              
          //error as:the method create disjunction is undefined for the type restrictions

    .add(Restrictions.eq("authLastname",   keywordsearch ))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("bookTitile", keywordsearch  ))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("description",   keywordsearch  )) 
                     );
```

I also tried [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/) to understand, but I am unable to solve my problem.

Comment: From the question it looks like you need a Criteria example, but the use case is actually much more suited to be solved with Hibernate Search, the Lucene integration module: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: i tried Hibernate Search also, though i am hibernate beginner i am afraid to implement it. Can you write one simple example for keyword search using Hibernate Search. With full description. And also mention which are the necessary jar for this. I read hibernate Search docs, but   am unable to implement it. So please show me a example with full description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.eq("author_name", keyword))
                                 .add(Restrictions.eq("book_title", keyword))
                                 .add(Restrictions.eq("description", keyword))
                                 .add(Restrictions.eq("publisher_name", keyword)));
```

You should also respect Java naming conventions. `author_name` should be `authorName`, `book_title` should be `bookTitle`, etc.

Comment: i tried  the code which you have shown me above.    But your code is showing error on `.createDisjunction()` . Please see my above code once again, i updated it.  if i use  `.createDisjunction()` one error appears like this "The method create disjunction is undefined for the type restrictions".  But if i use `.disjunction()` instead of `.createDisjunction()` then error is not showing.  Please help me to solve this new problem.

Comment: Yes, it's `disjunction()` and not `createDisjunction()`. Why didn't you try with this method? How about reading its javadoc to understand what it does?

Comment: i made it disjunction() ..now it is working fine. I read the documentation also. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Just to clarify this is a Hibernate ORM Critera query, not Hibernate Search.

Comment: @Hardy : same search i can do with Hibernate ORM Critera query & also by using Hibernate Search. So can you tell me which one will be better one and why?

Comment: Hibernate Search is good for free text searches where  you want to do things like applying analyzers (stemmers for different languages, synonyms, fuzzy searches etc). Take description for example. In your criteria query you use an equal on description. Assuming that description is multiple words at least you would only get a hit with Criteria if you match the whole description, whereas with Hibernate Search you can match single words in the description. It all comes down to your use case.

Comment: @Hardy: okay But if i use ` .add(Restrictions.like("description",   "%"+keywordsearch+"%"  )` .Then i can search matching single words in the description

Comment: Right '"%"+keywordsearch+"%" will give you some form of wildcards, but they are only at the beginning and end of the query terms. That is not the same as tokenizing the whole search string (and indexing tokenized as a matter of fact).

Answer (score 0):

For Hibernate Search it would look something like:

```
Query luceneQuery = mythQB
    .keyword()
    .onFields("authLastname","bookTitile","description")
    .matching(keywordsearch)
    .createQuery();
```

That is just the query part of course. You would need to enable Hibernate Search and add the right annotations, etc. It is all in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html). Start with the getting started section. It should contain all you need.

Comment: Okay as you suggested. i will start implementing this. But in middle if i get any doubt or problem. Then i will ask you. Will you help me?